# Firefox Browser Closes One Second After Opening, Ignoring Scenarios

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, cucumber, geckodriver

I use Firefox version 54.0.1 (64-bit), Geckodriver v0.17.0-win64 and Selenium 3.4.0 but when I run my scenarios Firefox opens and after one second closes. So, my scenarios ignored. I used different versions of Firefox, Geckodriver and Selenium. But not helped
This is my code:

```
private static WebDriver createConfiguredDriver() {

        final String driverName = TestData.getBrowser();   //BrowserType.FIREFOX
        final boolean remote = TestData.isRemoteMode();    //"webdriver.isremote";
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilites = new DesiredCapabilities(driverName, "", Platform.ANY);
        desiredCapabilites.setCapability("marionette", false);
        if (remote) {
            final String host = TestData.getBrowserHost();
            final int port = TestData.getBrowserPort();
            logger.info("Remote browser host: " + host);
            logger.info("Remote browser port: " + port);
            try {
                URL remoteAddress = new URL("http", host, port, "/wd/hub");
                return new RemoteWebDriver(remoteAddress, desiredCapabilites);
            } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to create remote URL using host: " + host, mue);
            }
        }
        else if (BrowserType.FIREFOX.equalsIgnoreCase(driverName)) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                    "src\\main\\resources\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
            logger.info("Using local FireFox WebDriver.");
//            desiredCapabilites.setCapability("firefox_binary", "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
            return new FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilites);
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.fluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluent-selenium</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.11</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         </dependencies>
         <profile>
            <id>firefox</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <webdriver.driver>firefox</webdriver.driver>
            </properties>
        </profile>
         <profile>
            <id>remote</id>
            <properties>
                <webdriver.isremote>true</webdriver.isremote>
                <webdriver.host>vwbnode01</webdriver.host>
                <webdriver.port>4444</webdriver.port>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Steps.java</include>
                        <include>**/*TestRunner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My console:

> rg.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
>   Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'WS00MU016', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '9.0.1'
>   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
>
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:137)
>       at com.dods.ui.mpp.tests.runner.CucumberTestRunner.createConfiguredDriver(CucumberTestRunner.java:60)
>       at com.dods.ui.mpp.tests.runner.CucumberTestRunner.init(CucumberTestRunner.java:84)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:192)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.start(XpiDriverService.java:94)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
>       ... 24 more

Comment: Try upgrading selenium to latest version also and see if it works. Gecko should be 0.18 at least I believe

Comment: I would like to also see where you're calling `createConfiguredDriver` and how you're disposing the driver. Have you stepped through the code to see exactly when the browser closes? Could it be possible you're accidentally disposing it before you use it?

Comment: I upgraded to Selenium 3.8.1 and Gecko 0.19 but still can`t run. The browser is getting opened but not able to get URL in the browser. And I have an error in console "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by matching:
GeckoDriver v0.19.0: Firefox 57.0.4(64-bit) & Selenium 3.4.0
The property "marionette" should set to true

Answer (score 0):

You could find below the recommended versions. I saw that your Selenium and the Gecko driver are already upgraded but *you should check also if the property "marionette" is set to true.*

GeckoDriver v0.19.0: Firefox 55.0 (and greater) & Selenium 3.5 (and greater)

GeckoDriver v0.18.0: Firefox 53.0 (and greater)

GeckoDriver v0.16.0: Selenium 3.4 (and greater)

Comment: Not helped, even if the property "marionette" is set to true. Tried a different version of GeckoDriver, Firefox& Selenium but browser opens and after one second closes